# GAE - What is the fastest way to add tasks to queue? Why does this appear to be so slow?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using Google App Engine (Python) to process some event messages in real time. In short I have 100+ tasks that I need to run fast when a message comes in. I have tried a few approaches (deferred library, threads) and I think the best solution involves using the task queue and asynchronously adding these tasks to the queue I want. Here's an example of what I am doing.

```
tasks = []
task = Task(url=url_for('main.endpoints_worker'),params={'id': id})
tasks.append(task.add_async(queue_name='event-message'))

for task in tasks:
    task.get_result()
```

When I do this most of my time is spent adding these tasks to the queue. Is there a way to speed this up? Is there a better approach?

[image: Example of Task Queue Bulk Add Time]

Now to be honest I get vastly different times each time I run this. Sometimes I am around 100ms (which would be fine) but other times I am up around 1s.

I would have thought spreading out the work would have been faster but bulk adding to the task queue out performs. With suggested approach below here is what I am seeing:

```
tasks = [Task(url=url_for('main.endpoints_worker'),params={'id': id}) for id in id_list]
rpc = Queue('event-message').add_async(tasks)
rpc.get_result()
```

[image]

**UPDATE: I need to examine this issue again due to the 100 task limit when adding to a queue.**
I have greatly improved the throughput of my code by batching the creation of my tasks (groups of 100) but I still don't understand why adding multiple groups of tasks to a queue slows down so quickly. One task queue.add_async runs < 40ms no issue. When I do 2 or more queue.add_async that time slows down. I would love to know why? Also how do I get around this?

[image]

When I add batches of tasks without async they each take < 40ms. Why do they take so much longer when async is used?

[image]

**Another Update** I thought the issue may be contention related but even when I add each of these tasks to a different queue I get the same results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save a ton of time by queuing your tasks in batches.  Something like the following should work for you:

```
tasks = [Task(url=url_for('main.endpoints_worker'),params={'id': id}) for id in id_list]
rpc = Queue('event-message').add_async(tasks)
rpc.wait()
```

Note that you can't submit tasks in batches with the deferred library.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing above. The queue add_async is equivalent to the task.add_async.

Comment: No, it isn't the same.  You are calling `task.add_async` for a *single* task at a time.  I am calling `Queue().add_async` with a *list* of tasks and that makes all the difference.

Comment: This looks like it does the trick. I thought It would be faster to add the tasks async one at a time as I worked with them. But I was wrong. Just one small thing with the code above. I believe it is rpc.get_result() and not rpc.wait(). As per the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/queues#Queue_add_async

Comment: @DavidWard, See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rpcclass

Comment: Right... But why would you not want to check_success? I guess if I don't care about retrying I could just wait.

Comment: do you know why the bulk add outperforms the individual queue.add_async(task)? Why does adding them one at a time push the time up so much?

Comment: I suspect each call of add_async is basically an internal REST API call so even though it is all within a Google data center you still need a round trip call to another computer each time you call add_async.  The same reason why ndb.put_multi is so much faster than individual puts.

Comment: Given that I have > 100 tasks to add at a time is there another solution here? I played with this some more and there is a 100 task limit when adding tasks to a queue (TooManyTasksError: No more than 100 tasks can be added in a single call). The second I chunk the results into 100 I am back to making multiple async calls to add_async and I see a slow down.

< 100 Tasks - One add - Time < 50ms
> 100 Tasks - Multiple adds - Time > 150ms (per add)