# Google App Engine - Python - Task Queue - How can i add a list of tasks?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have this code that works fine:

```
taskqueue.add(url = MY_URL, params={'id': 42}, queue_name='random-message')
```

In [this official document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.taskqueue) it says: "Adds a task or list of tasks into this queue."

But I can't understand how.

I already tried this:

```
tasks = []
tasks.append(taskqueue.Task(url = MY_URL, params={'id': 42}))
taskqueue.add(tasks, queue_name='random-message')
```

but It raises an error that I don't understand:

```
'Task payloads must be strings; invalid payload: %r' % payload)
```

I tried many others little variants that weren't working anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAE - What is the fastest way to add tasks to queue? Why does this appear to be so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456738/gae-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-add-tasks-to-queue-why-does-this-appear-to-be)

Comment: It actually is, kinda. I saw that post before asking but it seemed different because It used Queue.add(task). After more reading I found out that my taskqueue.add(task) is just a lazy function that cannot in any way receive more than 1 task at a time. But that question was so confusing to me and only after understanding my error It was useful. I will now anyway answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was:

```
taskqueue.add(task)
```

It cannot receive more than one task at a time. The right way to do that is this:

```
taskqueue.Queue.add(tasks)
```

My code is now working:

```
tasks = []
tasks.append(taskqueue.Task(url = MY_URL, params={'id': 42}))
taskqueue.Queue('random-message').add(tasks)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be having a naming conflict, since `tasks` is a parameter for the `.add()` method.  Try:

```
task_list = []
task_list.append(taskqueue.Task(url = MY_URL, params={'id': 42}))
taskqueue.add(tasks=task_list, queue_name='random-message')
```

or:

```
taskqueue.add(task_list, queue_name='random-message')
```

Comment: This was not the issue, tried both of them neither one of them worked.

Comment: Please update the question, then, and show the new error logs

Comment: No need to update, I found the solution and I posted It. It's up there :)
It's not marked yet because I have to wait a day.