# Bulk Enqueue Google Cloud Tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

As part of migrating my Google App Engine Standard project from python2 to python3, it looks like I also need to switch from using the Taskqueue API & Library to google-cloud-tasks.

In the taskqueue library I could enqueue upto 100 tasks at a time like this

```
taskqueue.Queue('default').add([...task objects...])
```

as well as enqueue tasks asynchronously.

In the new library as well as the new API, it looks like you can only enqueue tasks one at a time

- https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks/create
- https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudtasks/latest/gapic/v2/api.html#google.cloud.tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient.create_task

I have an endpoint where it receives a batch with thousands of elements, each of which need to get processed in an individual task. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation ([reference 1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/migrating-push-queues#features-not-available), [reference 2](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/migrating#features_in_task_queues_not_yet_available_via)) the feature of adding task to queues asynchronously (as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456738/gae-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-add-tasks-to-queue-why-does-this-appear-to-be/34457147#34457147) post suggests for adding bulk number of tasks to a queue), is **NOT** an available feature via Cloud Tasks API. It is available for the [users of App Engine SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#adding_tasks_asynchronously) though.

However, there is a [reference](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/manage-cloud-task-scaling#large-scalebatch_task_enqueues) in the documentation regarding adding a large number of Cloud Tasks to a queue via double-injection pattern workaround ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045153/rapidly-creating-cloud-tasks-using-cloud-task-cloud-functions-and-gae/59070912#59070912) might seem useful too).

> To implement this scenario, you'll need to create a new injector queue, whose single task would contain information to add multiple(100) tasks of the original queue that you're using. On the receiving end of this injector queue would be a service which does the actual addition of the intended tasks to your original queue. Although the addition of tasks in this service will be synchronous and 1-by-1, it will provide an asynchronous interface to your main application to bulk add tasks. In such a way you can overcome the limits of synchronous, 1-by-1 task addition in your main application.
>
> - Note that the **500/50/5 pattern of task addition to queue** is a suggested method, in order to avoid any (queue/target) overloads.

As I did not find any examples of this implementation, I will edit the answer as soon as I find one.

Since you are in a migration process, I figured out that [this link](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/migrating) would be useful, as it concerns migrating from Task Queue to Cloud Tasks (as you stated you are thinking to do).

Additional information on migrating your code with all the available details you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/pull/migrating-pull-queues) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/migrating-push-queues), regarding Pull queues to Cloud Pub/Sub Migration and Push queues to Cloud Tasks Migration correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but this feels like a severe downgrade from being able to run "AddMulti" and forget about it. Think this is the third appengine package replacement that feels like a downgrade when upgrading to Go 1.12 compatible packages.

Answer (score -1):

In order to recreate a batch pull mechanism, you would have to switch to Pub/Sub. Cloud Tasks does not have pull queues. With Pub/Sub you can [batch push](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching) and [batch pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) messages.

If you are using a push queue architecture, I would recommend passing those elements as the task [payload](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/flexible/tasks/create_app_engine_queue_task.py#L47); however the max task size is limited to [100kb](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas).

Comment: "I would recommend passing those elements as the task payload" so pass all of the elements into a single task? and then what? I was trying to have them all process in parallel. They need to get split into individual tasks at some point right? (I'm doing a batch push by the way)

Comment: That's probably not going to work for you then. I'm not sure if I understand your use case.

Comment: Each element is a transaction that I need to match to a user within my system. Once matched i potentially need to bill users which involves making a HTTP call to braintree. Regardless of use case, it should be more efficient to process each element in parallel in individual tasks rather than single task processing them all serially. Second, it is easier to make individual tasks idempotent in case a task hangs and gets re-run; with a single task processing them all serially, if it crashes and re-runs i'd need to have a mechanism where it can figure out where it left off last time.

Comment: You are right about the retry logic. Where is your tasks processing happening? If you set up your queue correctly and add each transaction to a task, your processor should be able to processes as many tasks as it can (near in-parallel). Or do your tasks need to share information?

Comment: It's happening on App Engine Standard Python2 (eventually to become Python3).  "add each transaction to a task, your processor should be able to processes as many tasks as it can" Right, once the tasks are enqueued I'm sure it will be fine. My concern is the ability to enqueue/add each transaction to a task. It sounds like the only way to do it is to loop through the batch of elements and enqueue them one at a time synchronously.